# How to have something similar to org-ctrl-c-minus but instead of adding just "-" Emacs would add "- [ ]"?

Tags: org-mode, text-editing

Suppose I have the following snippet inside an `.org` file:

```
The Need to Read
What You (Want to) Want
```

After selecting the region with the mark command and executing `org-ctrl-c-minus`,  I can convert the text to:

```
- The Need to Read
- What You (Want to)* Want
```

I want a similar output. But, with the `[ ]` after `-`.  So that I would have a list of items:

```
- [ ] The Need to Read
- [ ] What You (Want to)* Want
```

Of course, this could be achieved with a "search and replace" approach. However, I bet there is probably a command for this purpose.

Is there such a command? What is the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After converting the region to a list of items (as you did using `org-ctrl-c-minus`), you can select that same region and run the command `org-toggle-radio-button` with a prefix argument.

Using the default keybinding that would be `C-u C-c C-x C-r`.

Comment: ... or with `org-toggle-checkbox` with prefix argument: `C-u C-c C-x C-b`.  This works even if the selected region includes the final newline of the list and `point` is at the beginning of the next line. `C-u C-c C-x C-r` complains that it `Cannot toggle checkbox outside of a list` in that case.